# want to display multiple lines in custom cell label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a label in a custom cell with 3 labels in a table view. I am trying to display a text message "Updated status one of user" in one of the labels, but it displays only "Updated status" and truncates the rest of the message. What can I tweek to display the whole message in a line or spill it to a second line is necessary? Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, set the number of lines of your label to 0, and set its *lineBreakMode* to *UILineBreakModeWordWrap* if you want the text to wrap to more lines if it doesn't fit. Else, try increasing the width of your label.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this sample custom label creation in objective c and also how we can display no of lines in label , fallow the comments in below code it's useful to simply understand...

### in .h

```
UILabel *label;
```

### in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  

     label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60)];

     label.text=@"HI EVERY BODY >>> GOOD MORNING TO ALL MY DEAR FRIENDS";

     label.numberOfLines=2;  // for example i gave 2 lines , you can give how many lines  you want 

     label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // you must have to specify line Break mode

     [self.view addSubview:label];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

}

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UILabel's `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property for that.